# Calculating this double integral in polar coordinates

Tags: calculus

> Calculate the double integral $\iint_D {(1+x^2 + y^2)ln(1+x^2+y^2)dxdy} $ where $D = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 | \frac{x}{\sqrt3} \leq y \leq x , x^2 + y^2 \leq 4\}$.

I heard there is a way called Polar Coordinates but the more I looked and read about it the more I did not understand.

But I started drawing $D$ and wolfram gave this:

[image]

But doesn't $D$ also include the opposite direciton of this? And if so and if not, how would I calculate it with "Polar Coordinates?"
I know Polar Coordinates is a wide subject and I am sorry for asking it this way, but I did not understand scholar papers.

Comment: The inequality $x/\sqrt{3} \leqslant x$ implies $x \geqslant 0$. Note that $D$ is a circular sector, that means it's easy to parameterise in polar coordinates. The integrand is rotationally symmetric, so that is also _easily_ expressible in polar coordinates.

Comment: Just [put](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Generalization) $x^2+y^2=r^2$ and $dx dy=rd\theta d\phi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking @Daniel Fisher's comment to its logical conclusion, the lines imply a circular sector in which $\theta \in [\pi/6,\pi/4]$.  Thus the area integral is

$$\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4} d\theta \, \int_0^2 dr \, r \, (1+r^2) \, \ln{(1+r^2)}$$

Comment: are you sure $\theta \in [\pi / 4, \pi / 3]$? I mean, $arctan(1 / \sqrt3) = \pi / 6$

Comment: @TheNotMe: thanks for catching that; got her backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your sketch and remembering that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, it can be seen, in polar coordinates that your angle starts at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and moves up to $\frac{\pi}{6}$, whereas your radius, goes from 0 to 2, thus gving the following limits:

$\frac{\pi}{6}\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{4}$, $0\leq r\leq 2$

Your integral can now be rewritten in polar coordinates as 
\begin{align}I &=\int\limits_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} \int \limits_{r_0}^{r_2}f(x).r drd \theta \\ &=\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int \limits_{0}^{2}(1+r^2)ln(1+r^2)r drd \theta\end{align}which can be solved more easily than Cartesian coordinates.